# Make CMake search for doxygen only if the user builds doc

Tags: cmake

I add a `doc` target in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED dot)
doxygen_add_docs(doc
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This would require an installation of doxygen, even if the user doesn't build the documentation.

How to make CMake to search for an installation of doxygen only if the user build documentation with `make doc`?

Thanks.

Comment: Command `find_package` is executed on *configuration* stage, when user-specified targets are not known (they are defined only for *build* stage). You may move all doxygen-related code into separate `CMakeLists.txt`, and build it via `ExternalProject_Add` - this would be built on build stage. Alternatively, you may add *CMake* option (like `WITH_DOCUMENTATION`) for your project, which would enable building the documentation.

Comment: Would it be wrong to search for doxygen, then if it is not found just go on? You can do so simply removing REQUIRED